# sublime text / ms word delete misc line breaks in code

Tags: ms-word, sublimetext2

I have a csv file that has random line breaks throughout the file. (probably load errors when the file was created where the loader somehow managed to put a carriage return into the field)

How do I go in and remove all carriage returns / line breaks where the last character is not "

I have word and sublime text available for text editors

I have tried ^p with a letter infront and find and replace, but that doesnt seem to work for some of the lines for some reason

Example

```
"3203","Shelving Units

",".033"
```

instead of

```
"3203","Shelving Units",".033"
```

and

```
"3206","Broom
","1.00"
```

instead of

```
"3206","Broom","1.00"
```

Answer (score 0):

`Menu > Find > Replace...` or <kbd>Ctrl+H</kbd>

Select "Regular Expression" (probably a `.*` icon in the bottom left, depending on your theme).

Use `\n` to select newlines (LF) or `\r\n` (CRLF).

Answer (score 0):

As @GerardRoche said you can use search and replace in Sublime Text. Open it via `ctrl+h` and press `alt+r` to toggle regex to enable it. (You may want to create a backup of your file before doing such changes.)

Search for `(?<=[^"\n])\n+` and replace it with nothing, press Replace All or `ctrl+alt+enter` to replace it.
The regex just mean: search for alt least one (`+`) newlines (`\n`), that are preceded by something different than a quotation mark or a newline `(?<=[^"\n])`.

You don't need to worry about carriage returns, because ST only uses them when reading and writing the file and not in the editor.